# What attacks does Content Security Policy base-uri protect against?

Tags: html, content-security-policy

I have read up on [base-uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/base-uri) and the [HTML base tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1889076/461834), but what exactly is the `base-uri` CSP is meant to protect against?

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find any official reason. But generally, injection of a `base` tag can be used in HTML injections.

For example, consider that an attacker can only post very limited HTML (but can use `base`). Depending on the point of injection, they could now hijack existing forms to send the information (eg CSRF tokens, passwords, etc) to their server.

Of course, in this case setting `form-action` would be better than setting `base-uri`, but might not be practical (eg because legitimate users need to create arbitrary forms).

Another example would be a case where developers can't or don't want to restrict where scripts are loaded from. They have an XSS filter in place which prevents script injection, but they forgot to filter `base`. An attacker could now perform XSS via `base` HTML injection. Setting a `base-uri` would prevent this.

The examples might seem a bit far-fetched. But I would assume that it is these sorts of corner cases that the directives are meant to protect. The `base` tag has little practical use (at least in production), so why not provide the option to limit it?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy response header allows web site administrators to control resources the user agent is allowed to load for a given page. With a few exceptions, policies mostly involve specifying server origins and script endpoints. This helps guard against cross-site scripting attacks (XSS).

How does this work with base-uri? You would define base-uri to be your website's domain (i.e. example.com), this would limit includes to only be within the base-uri's domain.

As an example someone uses an XSS to do a remote include that loads an iframe (attacker.com/iframe.html) to steal users credentials. Since that is outside of base-uri that iframe will not load.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You seem to be describing security benefits of using the `<base>` tag. [base-uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/base-uri) does not set the `<base>` element. It restricts the values that may be used for `<base>`. So setting the CSP `base-uri` value will not do what you said -- adding a `<base>` element will. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @jtpereyda I think you're overstating the benefits as well, a `<base>` tag doesn't limit what scripts can be included, it simply determines where _relative_ paths will be included from. Absolute paths won't be affected.